# Confused with output differences between two simple loops

Tags: r

I am confused as to why the two pieces of code are returning different results.
In one the only difference between the loops is the use of **Wage$age.cut1** vs. **age.cut1**. What is the significance of the difference?

DATA: ISLR package, Wage data

```
 cv.err <- rep(NA, 10)
 for (i in 2:10){
   Wage$age.cut1 = cut(Wage$age, i)
   fit = glm(wage~age.cut1, data = Wage)
   cv.err[i] = cv.glm(Wage, fit, K = 10)$delta[2]
 }

> cv.err
[1]       NA 1733.646 1681.587 1636.521 1632.931 1623.112 1611.965 1600.903 1609.973
[10] 1607.234 # these are the expected results




 cv.err <- rep(NA, 10)
 for (i in 2:10){
   age.cut1 = cut(Wage$age, i)
   fit = glm(wage~age.cut1, data = Wage)
   cv.err[i] = cv.glm(Wage, fit, K = 10)$delta[2]
 }
 > cv.err
 [1]       NA 1603.255 1608.617 1602.296 1606.265 1606.139 1602.448 1606.063 1605.100
[10] 1606.986
```

Comment: I would bet that if you run the _same_ code twice that you would not get exactly the same result. Cross validation uses random selection of points to build the models and those points not used to test them.  If you run it twice,  you will get different random selections and different results.

Comment: Try setting the `set.seed(1)` in front of every `cv.err` and see if you get the same results.

Comment: Setting the random seed to one in both loops yields different results. Results consistent with my initial runs. as far as I can tell, both loops are the same, are they not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the difference of those two make a great difference in your loop logic. In first loop, *age.cut1* is a column in *Wage* dataframe evidenced by the `$` qualifier and **is used** in the `glm` formula. In second loop, *age.cut1* is a standalone, separate named vector and is **unused** in the `glm` formula. Whenever a formula is used, the columns derive from the object referenced in *data* argument.

Unfamiliar with listed packages and data structures, most likely `age.cut1` column does exist in `Wage` data frame prior to looping (since no error occurred in its reference in second loop's `glm` call). However, it is only updated in first loop with `cut(Wage$age, i)`. Though a similar named object is assigned in second loop, the original column data remains untouched in `glm`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!